# WSL: apt upgrade error because mongodb-org-server needs systemd

Tags: apt, windows-subsystem-for-linux, mongodb

in my WSL `apt upgrade` crashed because of a problem with mongodb-org-server.

I use WSL2 with Ubuntu 20.04. (The same error also appeared in WSL1 with Ubuntu 18.04 before I upgraded my WSL recently.)

Here is the output of `apt upgrade`:

```
[...]
Setting up mongodb-org-server (4.2.11) ...############################################################################################..............................]
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.##############################################################........................]
Failed to connect to bus: Host is down
dpkg: error processing package mongodb-org-server (--configure):
 installed mongodb-org-server package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mongodb-org:
 mongodb-org depends on mongodb-org-server; however:
  Package mongodb-org-server is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mongodb-org (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9.1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mongodb-org-server
 mongodb-org
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

With the help of this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30691665/cant-remove-purge-unistall-mongodb-from-debian) I figured out that the error comes from the file `/var/lib/dpkg/info/mongodb-org-server.postinst`, specifically from

```
# Check for changes to the service file
systemctl daemon-reload
```

because systemd is not available in WSL.

I commented out that line and now `apt upgrade` runs through.

**So here is my question:** Is it okay to just comment it out or can this cause problems? I'm kind of a newbie to Ubuntu and don't really know what I'm doing there.

Comment: WSL on Ubuntu is different than Ubuntu in a VM or on bare metal.  As you've discovered, it doesn't support `systemd` -- that's because it's not designed to run software in the background.  Not all applications are appropriate for WSL.  You probably should not use WSL to host a database. See: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/faq#can-i-run-all-linux-apps-in-wsl

Answer (score 0):

It's just a post install script to start the mongod daemon service after installation. It's quite harmless to comment that out. However, since WSL has no systemd, you'll have to start the mongod service manually at every reboot.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem by [upgrading MongoDB from **4.2** to **6**](https://df.tips/t/1943).

1. Run `sudo apt purge mongodb-org*` It solves the problem `trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/install_compass', which is also in package mongodb-org-tools 4.2.11`
2. 

```
sudo apt install gnupg 
curl mongodb.com/docs/v6.0/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-debian/#import-the-public-key-used-by-the-package-management…
```

Comment: The moderator has corrupted my answer and made it wrong. Please follow the real solution here: https://df.tips/t/1943